# Hover bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-hover, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm trying to use the `hover()` function of JQuery to do some formatting to my DatePicker when entering the mouse in one of its rows but unfortunately my `hover()` is never call.

Here is how I initialize my datepicker:

```
//WEEK PICKER
moment.locale('fr', {
  week: { dow: 1 } // Monday is the first day of the week
});

//Initialize the datePicker(I have taken format as mm-dd-yyyy, you can     //have your owh)
$("#weeklyDatePicker").datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'
});

//Get the value of Start and End of Week
$('#weeklyDatePicker').on('dp.change', function (e) {
    var value = $("#weeklyDatePicker").val();
    var firstDate = moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").weekday(0).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
    var lastDate =  moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").weekday(6).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
    $("#weeklyDatePicker").val(firstDate + " - " + lastDate);
});
```

Here is how I'm setting my `hover()` function:

```
$( ".bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget tr" ).hover(
  function() {
    console.log('in');
  }, function() {
    console.log('out');
  }
);
```

But no logs are being written. I'm sure to have the right selector because I got this in my CSS:

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget tr:hover {
    background-color: #808080;
}
```

And the color is updating when the mouse goes hover.

Any idea?

---

**EDIT**

Here is a Jfiddle that reproduce my code: https://jsfiddle.net/5kzjvL1u/

Comment: If `.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget` is being loaded into the DOM after the page has loaded (and I suspect it is) it cannot be selected in this fashion.  You'll need to do something like `$(body).on('hover', '.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget tr', function() { });`

Comment: It doesn't seems to change anything. But actually I don't think that the `.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget` is loaded before the page because it is shown only after a click on an input field. Do I have to call the `hover()` on the `click event` of the input?

Comment: Would be easier to troubleshoot if we could see the code in action to better know what's all going on.

Comment: I added a JSFiddle that reproduce my code

Comment: The `.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget tr` elements are almost undoubtedly dynamically created. CSS will style dynamically created elements, and jQuery will select them if the correct syntax is used. Try using the `$(ancestor).on('hover', descendent, fn)` form of `.on()`, where `ancestor` is a static container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Robert C is correct in his comment in that it's being loaded intor the DOM after the page has loaded and you are correct in your suggestion of placing the `:hover` within a click event for the input field. See this snippet for a working example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  moment.locale('fr', {
    week: {
      dow: 1
    } // Monday is the first day of the week
  });

  //Initialize the datePicker(I have taken format as mm-dd-yyyy, you can     //have your owh)
  $("#weeklyDatePicker").datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'
  });

  $('#weeklyDatePicker').on('dp.change', function(e) {
    var value = $("#weeklyDatePicker").val();
    var startDate = moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").weekday(0).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
    var endDate = moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").weekday(6).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
    $("#weeklyDatePicker").val(startDate + " - " + endDate);
  });

  $("#weeklyDatePicker").click(function() {
    $(".bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget tr").hover(
      function() {
        console.log('in');
      },
      function() {
        console.log('out');
      }
    );
  });
});
```

```css
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget tr:hover {
  background-color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <div class="input-group" id="DateDemo">
        <input type='text' id='weeklyDatePicker' placeholder="Select Week" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but probably leaky. Js event handlers have a nasty tendency to hang around even when the nodes to which they are attached have been removed from the DOM.

Comment: I undo my acceptance because I'm still stuck on an issue with this: hen we click on the next or prev button it doesn't work anymore. I tried to add a click callback on those button inside the click callback of the input but it does not work, any idea?

Comment: You could switch from `.hover` to `mouseenter` and use event delegation to target the rows. You can then use `mouseleave` on `.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget` to detect when leaving the box as a whole. [DEMO codepen](https://codepen.io/jbanegas/pen/WZWzZz?editors=1111) . If this achieves your goal, I will update my answer.

Comment: It achieves my goal. The only detail I updated in your codepen demo is that I added the "tr" element for the `mouseleave` event (like in `mouseenter`)